# How can I secure my Android app against unauthorized modifications or APK patching using PackageManager signatures?

Tags: android, kotlin, security, android-package-managers

I would like to ask a question regarding `Unauthorized Application Modification` or `APK Patching` in the context of Android. How can I secure my application against this threat? Is using `PackageManager` an effective tool for implementing protection against unauthorized modifications, and if so, how can it be done?
I could get a signatures of an instlalled package and then what? Thanks for any advice

Comment: Any in-app detection of modifications will be unreliable, because the one making the modifications can simply remove that in-app detection logic.

Comment: What could be correct a solution?

Comment: @CommonsWare ...and how it is possible someone could remove it from application if app is obfuscated, so from my understanding he doesn't know what exactly is written?

Comment: "how it is possible someone could remove it from application if app is obfuscated" -- your question assumes that the attacker can modify the app. There is nothing magic about in-app detection code that makes it different than the rest of your code. If the attacker can modify other aspects of your code, the attacker can modify your in-app detection code.

Comment: Ok, I understand your answer but how can I find the solution for my problem do you have one?

Comment: or anyway how would you use PackageManager?